# SSH jumphost does not execute ForceCommand

Tags: ssh

When I have a "ForceCommand" in my SSHD config, when I directly login to the host, I see the script specified in the "ForceCommand" being executed. However, when I use the host as a Jumphost, I don't see "ForceCommand" being executed, my intention is to write a script to validate if the user can connect to the destination host from a jumphost perspective. Any ideas on how to make a jumphost call a script that can do this?